# mysql query select between dates shows wrong answer

Tags: mysql

When I write a query in MySQL, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` where date BETWEEN '01/20/2012' AND '01/31/2012'
```

it also shows the details of 2013 customers.

Can any one help me please..

Comment: whats the date field type?

Comment: You **DO** know there's a datatype `DATETIME` in MySQL?

Comment: As far as I know, `01/29/2013` is `BETWEEN` the given range.

Comment: the range is b/w 2012 year only...but it shows 2013 year results..

Comment: @sandeep What is the datatype of the `date` column?

Comment: @sandeep: Store dates in `DATE` columns, not in `CHAR` columns.

Comment: nw i cant change the type..because if i change the type i loss the data in date fields..

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to convert the `VARCHAR` to a `DATE` to compare it;

```
SELECT *
FROM `customer` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')
BETWEEN '2012-01-20' AND '2012-01-31'
```

[An SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff772/2).

Note that this will miss any indexes you have on your column since every row needs to be converted before comparison, not good for performance.

Storing dates in a VARCHAR is generally seen as a bad idea, the sort order is non trivial and month/day can easily be confused if the system is used internationally. I'd recommend you convert the date column to a `DATE` datatype instead.

EDIT: This is one way of converting the column without losing your existing data;

```
# Add a new DATE column
ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD COLUMN tmpdate DATE;
# Transfer the data from the VARCHAR column to the DATE column
UPDATE `customer` SET tmpdate=STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y');
# Drop the old VARCHAR column
ALTER TABLE `customer` DROP COLUMN `date`;
# Rename the new DATE column to `date`.
ALTER TABLE `customer` CHANGE `tmpdate` `date` DATE;
```

Of course you should *never* attempt an alter table command without doing a proper backup first.

[An SQLfiddle demonstration of the conversion](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cce5b/1).

Note that PHP code relying on the date format may need some updating to work with `DATE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(dateField, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '01/20/2012' AND '01/31/2012';
```

Try this way.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Date & Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(dateField, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/20/2012', '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('01/31/2012', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `date` field type is `DATE`;

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-01-20' AND '2012-01-31'
```

From manual;

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

**UPDATE**

However, it's bad idea to store dates as `varchar`, maybe the query could be like:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `date` REGEXP '^2012-01-(2[0-9]|[0-3][0-9])$'
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

**But if it's possible, you need to exactly change your field type from `VARCHAR` to `DATE`.**

Comment: That's why there is a `DATE` datatype, to store dates eficiently and then using comparison operators (`= < <= > >= BETWEEN`) safely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the datatype of your `date` to `DATETIME` or simply, `DATE` like this:

   ```
   UPDATE `customer`
       SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE( `date`, '%m/%d/%Y' );
   ```
2. After the update, use `ALTER` like this:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `customer`
       CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATE NOT NULL;
   ```
3. After that, use this kind of select query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM `customer`
   WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-01-20' AND '2012-01-31';
   ```

---

The reason behind why is changing the datatype good, is explained here: [When to use `VARCHAR` and `DATE`/`DATETIME`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4759012/1190388)

Read other date and time related datatypes here: [The `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Comment: Just as a side note, if you use this method, make sure the VARCHAR `date` column has enough space to fit the result from STR_TO_DATE, or things may turn out in a bad way.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `01/20/2012` = 10 characters, `2012-01-20` = 10 characters.

Comment: Yes, in this case it _will_ work, but someone with a date format 01/02/03 may want to double check. Been there, done that, not happy with myself :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` where date BETWEEN '2012/01/20' AND '2012/31/01'
```

It will run now because phpmyadmin has been upgraded