# how to create trigger after update if the given date is equal to the current date

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is the table i had created

```
CREATE TABLE dob (name VARCHAR(20),date VARCHAR(100));
```

This is the data i had loaded in to the table dob

```
uttej,2017-08-22
venki,1997-07-15
porna,1995-05-11
pp,1997-07-07
```

[image]

This is the query i had written but there is an error

delimiter |

```
CREATE TRIGGER test after update on dob
for each row
begin
update dob where date = SELECT NOW();
end;
```

|

[image]
need some help ???????

Comment: Would you like to tag your database? sql, mysql, sqlite, ....

Comment: Do not post pictures of text. Prefer to post a [mcve] in the shape of one line of `create ...` and several lines of `insert ... `.

Comment: You should set your date column to a valid [date and time type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) instead of VARCHAR. Read [When to use VARCHAR and DATE/DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759039/5395709)

Comment: By replacing varchar with datetime i am getting the output as 00:00:0000 in the place of time and the date is displaying correctly.what i wanted is only date has to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your syntax error:

```
CREATE trigger test after update on dob
begin
  UPDATE dob SET date = NOW();
end;
```

But I am concerned that this will not have the outcome you desire, because if the field `dob` refers to date of birth, then you wouldn't want to be changing that every time the row gets updated...

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
  UPDATE dob SET date = NOW()' at line 2
 This is the error it is showing ... @Dave